# function is not defined error, but debugger shows it loaded and console can run it

Tags: javascript

I have read many posts on SO on this topic but my problem persists.
In the 'DOMContentLoaded' event I add a script file with this code:

```
let script   = document.createElement("script");
script.src   = "langs/" + calLang + "/calendar.js";
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Later in the same event I try to use a function from the loaded script.  I get the error 'Uncaught ReferenceError: dayNumberToName is not defined'.

If I go to the debugger I can see that the script file is loaded.  I can go to the console hit the 'd' key and a dropdown opens up showing the function.  I can select it and run it in the console with no problems.  I have appended the script file to the head and body sections but it made no difference, still not working.  No other errors show up in the console.

Can anyone give me a hint on why this is happening?

Thanks for any help,

Charles

Comment: "_Later in the same event_". Dynamically created scripts are loaded asynchronously. Attach `load` event to the script element and run what you need in that load handler.

Comment: @Teemu, thank you, my old brain was too tired to think of that.